# Firebase '.get()' does not return any data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I had this query:

```
this.firestore.collection('name', ref => ref.limit(1)).get().subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

That didn't return any data

[image: angualr]

Just for a test I changed that to this a and it works:

```
this.firestore.collection('name', ref => ref.limit(1)).valueChanges().subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

However I want to use `.get()`, any ideas what is the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.subscibe` method deals with `Observable`. It's simlar mechanizm like in Promise, but different.([reference](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html))

According to [this reference](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md) `valueChanges()`:

> - Returns an Observable of document data. All Snapshot
>     metadata is stripped. This method provides only the data

While `get()` takes snapshot using Promise mechanism. So you cannot use `subscribe` with get.

I hope it will help!